# "Proximity Search" and "Or" Clause does not seem to work

Tags: search, full-text-search

I have input `"update identnumber"~5 OR "identnumber update"~5` as the search text but it does not highlight the following line. If however I use `"N'update identnumber"~5 OR "identnumber N'update"~5` as the search text then the line below is highlighted.I am using the DocFetcher tool if that helps. What am I missing?

```
SET @sql = N'update IdentNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `"N'update identnumber"~5 OR "identnumber N'update"~5` as the search text and get the

```
SET @sql = N'update IdentNumber
```

line to be highlighted.